# Allow middleware and Route handlers to run together

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't seem to understand why my custom route handler doesn't pickup the value set within a custom middleware. Here's what I'm working with:

// my route

```
router.post('/login', bodyParser.text({type: 'urlencoded'}), function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
  console.log('access token is: ' + req.access_token); // This returns undefined

  var options = httpconn.httpOptions({
    resource: 'uaa',
    resourcePath: '/uaa/authenticate',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': ' application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.access_token} // @todo get from the middleware that sets it
  });
  var httpRequest = application.httprequest(options, function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        res.send(chunk);
    });
  });
  httpRequest.on('error', function(e) {
    res.status(500);
    res.send({'error': 'Authentication Failed: ' + e.message});
    return;
  });
  httpRequest.write(req.body);
  httpRequest.end();
});
```

// custom middleware

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

  redisSessionStore.getAsync('active_session').then(function(data) {
    req.access_token = data.access_token;
    console.log('retrieved access_token: ' + req.access_token);
  });
  next()
});
```

If I remove `bodyParser.text({type: 'urlencoded'})` from the route, I get a Bad request error.

The custom middleware doesn't seem to run as seen in req.access_token returning undefined.

Any pointers please?

Comment: try req.body.access_token or req.params.access_token

Comment: `access_token` is set as `req.access_token`

Comment: Sorry missed it. If you remove bodyParser, req.body will be undefined and as per your code it should return bad request. Order is important in the router, middleware and then your routing. Do you see the value in the middleware for req.access_token

Comment: Add router.use(bodyParser.text({type: 'urlencoded'})) before defining your routes(i.e post /login) and remove it from your post route.

Comment: Thanks. Adding router.use(bodyParser.text({type: 'urlencoded'})) and removing it from the route still doesn't invoke the middleware. Also doing `router.use(bodyParser.text({type: 'urlencoded'}))` makes it available to all routes. I really don't want that.

Comment: I can see the req.access_token value in the middleware as well as other routes which doesn't use `bodyParser.text({type: 'urlencoded'})`

Answer (score 0):

The `next()` was placed improperly. It should be:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

  redisSessionStore.getAsync('active_session').then(function(data) {
    req.access_token = data.access_token;
    console.log('retrieved access_token: ' + req.access_token);
    next()
  });
});
```

Comment: its clear now. next() was getting called before getAsync, as it should be.